# How to know the child number of parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

On a particular item, how can I know what the current child count is?

for example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <img id="lorem" />
  <img id="ipsum" />
  <img id="dolor" />
  <img id="sit" />
  <img id="amet" />
</div>
```

how can I know $('#sit') is # 4 of its siblings ?
I could iterate over all children and count but this seams very slow especially because I need to update it quite often and because there are hundreds of siblings and I only need to target the last 5 siblings

A workaround to my solution would be to be able to target the last 5 children's independently. Any idea how?

Comment: FYI, `.index` internally probably does nothing else but iterate over the siblings/children. There is no DOM property which contains the index of the element. You can only get it by traversing the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.index()`

```
$('#sit').index() // will give you the index (zero based) with respective to its siblings.
```

And if you want to find last 5 children of the parent, try:

```
 $('#parent').children(':nth-last-child(-n + 5)');
```

Comment: nice exactly what I was looking for thanks, accept as answer in 7m

Comment: Or `$('#parent').children().slice(-5)`, which personally I found a bit easier to read.